# Insert New Row, Merge Across, Color, Row Height

Tags: excel, vba

to begin, I find this site very helpful to resolve the seemingly endless issues with VBA's that I create.  I have very little experience making VBA's but I find creating them quite challenging but rewarding when things work in the way I envision them to work.

So here is i my issue.  I need to create a VBA to insert a new row anytime a cell in Column T is "Yes".  Column T is configured for Data Validation (Yes, No).  For the newly inserted row, i would like it to merge across from column D to X, change row height to autofit, and change cell color to 15 (light gray).  I have the insert row part figured out but i can't get the last part.

Anyone that has any suggestions, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks so much

Here is what I got, this part works:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If target.Column = 20 Then
    If target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows(target.Row + 1).Insert
    
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try Macro recorder, then have a look at the code as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim D_To_X as Range

    If target.Column = 20 Then
        If target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Rows(target.Row + 1).Insert

            ' Set the range from column D to X (4 to 24)
            Set D_To_X = Range(Cells(target.Row + 1, 4), Cells(target.Row + 1, 24))

            D_To_X.Rows.AutoFit
            D_To_X.Merge True
            D_To_X.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the next adapted event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

    If target.column = 20 Then
        If target.Value = "Yes" Then
            rows(target.Row + 1).insert
           
            With Intersect(rows(target.Row + 1), Me.Range("D:X"))
                .merge
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Insert Row

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column = .Worksheet.Columns("T").Column Then
                If .Value = "Yes" Then ' case-sensitive; no errors
                    With .EntireRow
                        .Offset(1).Insert
                        With .Offset(1).Columns("D:X")
                            .Merge
                            .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                            .EntireRow.AutoFit
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```